# Inherit build plugin/extension/... in Maven

Tags: maven, build-tools, maven-extension

Say a Maven project has a cool build plugin configured:

```
<project>
    ...
    <build>
       ... extensions etc.
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

I want this configuration to be reusable, so that I can run the goals provided by the plugins/extensions in any new project. The above project might exist just so that other projects can reuse the config.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `parent.pom`. Deploy this `pom` to your local repository. Of course you could configure `parent.pom`s for each type of project that you regularly develop in your organisation. Probably a `master.pom` with general values (location of servers, organisation name, general code style...) is a good idea. The project specific `pom`s would use this as parent.

Comment: In a multiproject project, the "plugin parent" should be the parent of the main, top-level pom, right? What If I want to add this behavior to a single child (module) of the main pom, not do all modules? It already has a parent (the top-level pom)...

Comment: Yes, in that case only the top level `pom` can have an external parent, the modules inherit via this but you can't give modules individual behaviour this way. This method works only with projects. Sometimes this is a hint that a module could be a project instead (but not always, sadly).

Answer (score 2):

Declare this `pom.xml` as of type `pom`:

```
<type>pom</type>
```

and declare it as a parent in every "child" `pom.xml` that needs the configured plugins: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance